# loss of WiFi access

Tags: wireless, 20.04

In recent weeks my `Ubuntu 20.04.3 LTS` system on an `HP EliteBook 840 G2` has lost WiFi access spontaneously. This happens with both FireFox and Skype. Both applications are able to display a message about the loss of internet access.

Running `Software Updater` does not seem to fix the problem.

One solution is to "log out" and "log in".

What is a superior solution, please?

Comment: Look at the logs!  `sudo  journalctl -b 0 -u NetworkManager`. Read `man journalctl`.